# How to create more Timeouts or interval in the same time

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I have a problem with making timeouts or intervals together...
My question is how to create more than one timeout or interval in the same time.
I try something like this:

```
    for (var i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.timer = setTimeout(function() { 
            // some images to draw or remove multiply 
        }, 1000);
    }
```

but it doesn't work

for example:
I need to make multiply timeout images when I click on canvas. Every image must be remove in one second since my click..

Thanks for all help and sorry for my bad english (student)...

Comment: Your loop just replaces the previous `this.timer` with the new one, so in the end you'd have only one timeout. You'd need a new variable for each one.

Comment: @Skwal almost correct, he'll spawn several timeouts but only has a reference to the last one

Comment: @Ken Yeah I just realized, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no point to set several timeout that will end at the same time anyway. And your code is fine, except that only the reference to the last timeout will be stored in `this.timer` (thanks @Ken).

The correct way to do this would be :

```
this.timer = setTimeout(function() { 
    for (var i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // do something to all images at the same time
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: to draw images? there might be a reason. But I understand what you're saying. There's a better way to do that.

Comment: @Seth since all the timeout end at the same time, I'm not sure there would be any good reason.

Comment: +1 @Skwal that is a good point. There can be different ranges invoked at different times but there is no sign of that in OPs code. A single timer is the better approach. Combined with timestamps even better.

Comment: @Skwal If you wanted to have 4 images generated at the same time, but like a said, better ways to do it. More than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: @Seth Still one timeout is enough :) Don't get me wrong, your answer is right too, but to me it's bad logic.

Comment: @Skwal so you would use one timeout and just fire the function like so `function(); function(); function()`, using the example that n images are to be generated after x seconds??

Comment: @Seth Well you have the loop for that.

Comment: @Skwal I understand what you're saying now.